# Typescript Redux tool kit axios dispatch logout action

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-toolkit

I've got this interceptor set up

```
const setupAxiosInterceptors = (onUnauthenticated: () => void) => {
  const onRequestSuccess = (config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
    console.log("request success", config);
    const token = Storage.local.get("auth");
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    return config;
  };
  const onRequestFail = (error: AxiosError) => {
    console.log("request error", error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
  };
  axios.interceptors.request.use(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);

  const onResponseSuccess = (response: AxiosResponse) => {
    console.log("response success", response);
    return response;
  };
  const onResponseFail = (
    error: { status: number } & { response: { status: number } }
  ) => {
    const status = error.status || error.response.status;
    if (status === 403 || status === 401) {
      onUnauthenticated();
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  };
  axios.interceptors.response.use(onResponseSuccess, onResponseFail);
};
export default setupAxiosInterceptors;
```

This action using react tool kit

```
export const authLogoutEffects = () => (
  dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>
) => {
  dispatch(authLogout());
  Storage.local.remove("auth");
};
```

Then in my index.ts

```
const { dispatch } = store;
setupAxiosInterceptors(() => {
  dispatch(authLogoutEffects());
});
```

the store is a instance of configureStore react toolkit

but I've got an error in the dispatch param

> Argument of type '(dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>) =>
>   void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction |
>   LocationChangeAction'.   Type '(dispatch:
>   ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>) => void' is missing the following
>   properties from type 'LocationChangeAction': type,
>   payloadts(2345)

Can you help me, please?